# Set property aura component ''Start hero under header'' on custom Theme Layout Component

Tags: community-builder, custom-theme-layout

I need to set this theme setting of standard Theme Layout Starter:

[image]

In custom Theme Layout Component like this:

[image]

To get this result, the header inside the hero, example:
[image]

Thank you